# RestfulService to read xml file returning not found

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to read a XML file using RestfulService but I am getting this in the response object
`[statusDescription:protected] => Not Found`

My Code:

```
$service = new RestfulService("offices.xml", 55555);
$conn = $service->request();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($conn);
die();
```

My XML File contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationalUnits>
   <OrganisationalUnit>
      <OrganisationalUnitID>86156</OrganisationalUnitID>
      <LocationName>Sydney</LocationName>
   </OrganisationalUnit>
</OrganisationalUnits>
```

Response:

```
RestfulService_Response Object
(
    [simpleXML:protected] => 
    [cachedResponse:protected] => 
    [statusCode:protected] => 404
    [statusDescription:protected] => Not Found
    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
            [Cache-Control] => private
            [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
            [Server] => Microsoft-IIS/8.5
            [X-Aspnetmvc-Version] => 5.2
            [X-Aspnet-Version] => 4.0.30319
            [X-Powered-By] => ASP.NET
            [Date] => Fri, 19 Mar 2021 10:14:40 GMT
            [Set-Cookie] => Array
                (
                    [0] => visid_incap_1691324=o5ESERquQOyKxF6eWsLrzJB5VGAAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAA7kZ0OU9qXzJesKsOtzCJo; expires=Fri, 18 Mar 2022 18:33:53 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.harcourts.co.nz
                    [1] => nlbi_1691324=cjOFR0CFjDC+GI+wA0eicgAAAADOQsauDet9Znt1zYKz0jY3; path=/; Domain=.harcourts.co.nz
                    [2] => incap_ses_339_1691324=Uj0Ubae+4E6jQYamKF+0BJB5VGAAAAAAjJUgbSWndbIWQpz2aOcfIg==; path=/; Domain=.********.co.**
                )

            [X-Cdn] => Imperva
            [X-Iinfo] => 14-215845415-215845416 NNNY CT(0 0 0) RT(1616148880653 0) q(0 0 0 -1) r(0 0) U11
        )

    [body:protected] =>
```

Comment: please put an online XML file to be sure that you don't have access to your XML file or the file dosn not exist in the location in question.

Comment: Maybe your path should be absolute and not relative? `new RestfulService(__DIR__ . "/path/to/file/offices.xml", 55555);`

Comment: @MoxGeek I am using this URL `http://christchurch.harcourts.co.nz/offices.xml` and the file is present there.

Comment: @Justinas I also tried absolute path but still it is giving same error

Comment: The [url cited](https://christchurch.harcourts.co.nz/offices.xml) yields a 404-Not Found - if this is your domain then you should know the correct path

Comment: it's 404 already ... you link isn't working mate ,change to another XML file

Comment: @MoxGeek I installed SSL and then it started working fine now. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome :) , have fun , happy coding